# In Github, How do we restrict pushes to a branch, but allow others to delete it?

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

We are currently using branch protection in github to restrict who can push code to our release candidate branches.  After we're done with the release, we'd like to get rid of the RC branch, but because it's restricted, no one can remove it, not even administrators.  I can't find any open PRs, it's merged into master, and seemingly ready to delete, but the github informs us we are not able to delete it.

Removing branch protections does allow us to delete the branch, but this seems like a long way to go to clean things up.  Has anyone dealt with this sort of scenario differently?  My ultimate goal is to limit who can merge code into our release candidate branches, and allow them to delete them as they see fit, while developers can't.